# iOS Messaging in app Not working Properly

Tags: iphone, ios, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller, imessage

I am Working on an RSS app where it needs to send the url of the article through a message. I have this code so far,

```
 MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] ;{
            if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
            {
                controller.body = @"Check Out This Informtaion, %@", [NSURL URLWithString:self.feedItem[@"url"]];
                controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: nil];
                controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
                [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
            }}
```

And it will work, it opens up the Messages in-app, but all it says in the message is

`Check Out This Information, %@`

When I do the same

`[NSURL URLWithString:self.feedItem[@"url"]];`

for opening up the page in Safari, it works, so that is correct, but I don't know how to fix it, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
controller.body = @"Check Out This Informtaion, %@", [NSURL URLWithString:self.feedItem[@"url"]];
```

is equivalent to

```
controller.body = @"Check Out This Informtaion, %@";
[NSURL URLWithString:self.feedItem[@"url"]];
```

…because the two statements are executing independently.

As user2056143 pointed out, you’re missing an NSString -stringWithFormat: around your values. I.e.:

```
controller.body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Check Out This Informtaion, %@", [NSURL URLWithString:self.feedItem[@"url"]]];
```

Comment: I will try this in a few minutes, don't have access to my Mac right now thanks

Comment: While I am thinking about it, do y'all know of a stack-overflow question for implementing the share button like in the safari ios app. The one with icons and the different sharing options.

Comment: Yep—search for UIActivityViewController

Answer (score 1):

Change body to :

```
controller.body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Check Out This <a href=\"%@\">Information<\a>", self.feedItem[@"url"]];
```

Comment: I've fixed the formatting (start a line with 4 spaces to make it code) but I don't think you need to use HTML for this; the message body probably just plain text.